# Error 299 when trying to read process memory

Tags: c#, winapi

i'm having some problem with reading process's memory, all i get is error 299, sometimes error 5/6, i'm new to memory reading / writing and can use any help.

This is what i have so far :

```
    private void ScanMemory()
    {
        uint PID;
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(GetWindowHandle(), out PID);
        label3.Text = "" + (int)PID;
        int valueToSearch = 4;
        List<int> matchAddresses = new List<int>();
        long MaxAddress = 0x7fffffff;
        long address = 0;
        do
        {
            MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION32 m;
            IntPtr Handle = OpenProcess((int)ProcessAccessFlags.All, false, (int)PID);
            uint result = VirtualQueryEx((int)Handle, (int)address, out m, (int)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION32)));
            if (address == (long)m.BaseAddress + (long)m.RegionSize)
                break;
            address = (long)m.BaseAddress + (long)m.RegionSize;
            SearchIntSizeValue(Handle, (int)m.BaseAddress, (int)m.RegionSize, valueToSearch, matchAddresses);
        } while (address <= MaxAddress);

        foreach (int res in matchAddresses)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(res);
        }
    }
    public void SearchIntSizeValue(IntPtr hProcess, int startAddress, int endAddress, int valueToSearch, List<int> addresses)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4];
        IntPtr bytesread;
        while (startAddress < endAddress)
        {
            ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, (IntPtr)startAddress, buffer, 4, out bytesread);
            int res = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0);
            if (res == valueToSearch)
            {
                addresses.Add(startAddress);
            }
            else
            {
                int le;
                if ((le = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()) != 0)
                {

                }
            }
            startAddress += 4;
        }
    }

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
 struct MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION32
{
    public uint BaseAddress;
    public uint AllocationBase;
    public int AllocationProtect;
    public uint RegionSize;
    public int State;
    public int Protect;
    public int lType;
}
```

i'm reading size of int at the moment, not really working :|, from reading in google, i saw there is this thing with privilege , though, i run vs2010 with Admin rights on windows 7, i hope it's enough information for you to spot my problme, thanks in advance!

Comment: Always check the results of every API function and call GetLastError to figure out what caused a failure.

Comment: well VirtualQueryEx returns 28, not sure if it's ok

Comment: That means it doesn't fail. What does ReadProcessMemory return?

Comment: 0, clearly it's  a fail, also, number of read bytes is 0

Comment: You do not appear to be testing the result of ReadProcessMemory here.

Comment: * will check in a sec, didn't noticed that

Comment: weird !!!  as soon as i wrapped the readProcessMemory func with if , it's working o_0!!! is it a must to check the results? i mean, will it not work if i don't check the results?!

Comment: It can still work if you don't check the results. You just won't know whether or not it worked. If you want to know whether it worked, you have to check the return code.

Comment: ok, good to know, another question, on the first iteration of my code, the m.BaseAddress is 0, is it normal? i mean, isn't base address must start in some location in the memory other then 0 ? and if it's just the offset, how can i get the real start location at the momory ?

Comment: Error 299 is very common when you try to do this in a 32-bit process on the 64-bit version of Windows.  Change the Platform target setting on your EXE project to AnyCPU.  And change the value of MaxAddress to ulong.MaxValue.

Answer (score 0):

Me helped solution on [www.codeproject.com](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/170017/Solving-Problems-of-Monitoring-Standard-Output-and):  [Solving-Problems-of-Monitoring-Standard-Output](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/170017/Solving-Problems-of-Monitoring-Standard-Output-and).

Solution protect application from additional deadlocks that Microsoft does not mention in their documentation.